# How to preserve all the filters in the form after reloading the view in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have the following form in the view:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{route('dsp.report')}}">
@csrf <!-- {{ csrf_field() }} -->
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label>Range one: </label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_from" name="date_from" placeholder="Date from range">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label>Range two: </label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_to" name="date_to" placeholder="Date to range">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label>Filter by SSP: </label><select name="ssp_id[]" id="ssp" class="form-control-lg select2" multiple="multiple"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label>Filter by DSP: </label><select name="dsp_id[]" id="dsp" class="form-control-lg select2" multiple="multiple"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
            <label>Group by: </label>
            <select class="form-control" name="groupby">
                <option>SSP/DSP</option>
                <option>SSP</option>
                <option>DSP</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to preserve all the values in this form after controller processed the request and returned data back:

```
        return view('dsp.index', $data);
```

How can I do it? Is there any simple solution?

**UPD**: To make it clear for preserving values (not keys) in select2-based multiple dropdown ajax selects:

First of all, we trigger this controller when we're looking for the SSP term:

```
public function get_ssp(Request $request) {
    $term = $request->get('term');

    $ssp_list = SspCompanyList::where('ssp_company_name', 'LIKE', '%'. $term['term'] .'%')
        ->get(['ssp_company_id as id', 'ssp_company_name as text']);

    return ['results' => $ssp_list];

}
```

And then we process chosen ids in the controller after submitting. Select2 has been configured in this way:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ssp').select2({
            width: '200px',
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            ajax: {
                url: '{{ route("get_ssp") }}',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                quietMillis: 50,
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        term: term
                    };
                },
            },
        });
    });
```

but the problem is that select2 sends only ids in ssp_id[], not key-value items, and it's not possible to recover them from old() function as item names before sending.

**UPD2**:
I'm trying to solve it in this way:

```
            <select name="ssp_id[]" id="ssp" class="form-control-lg select2" multiple="multiple">
                @if (is_array(old('ssp_id')))
                    @foreach (old('ssp_id') as $ssp_id)
                        {{ $ssp_name = \App\Models\SspCompanyList::select('ssp_company_name')->where('ssp_company_id', $ssp_id)->first()->ssp_company_name }}
                        <option value="{{ $ssp_name }}" selected="selected">{{ $ssp_name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            </select>
```

and after first reload it works and preserves the ssp names I need, but after second attempt to select values for dsp below on the same page and submit again it returns this error:

> Trying to get property 'ssp_company_name' of non-object (View:
> /home/pavel/projects/dsp/resources/views/dsp/index.blade.php)

So, why first time it's working and second time - not? Should we treat it in the other manner for select2?

Comment: You can use session to store filters data, and use session data in blade template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:**
You forgot to add the `value` attribute on your `select` `options`

For the normal Input Fields, you can pass the old value to it by using [Laravel's](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#old-input) `old('input_name')`

For Example:

```
<input name="input_name" value="{{ old('input_name') }}" />
```

While your Select Fields need the `selected` attribute on each `option` tag.

For example:

```
<select class="form-control" name="input_name">
    <option {{ old('input_name') == "SSP/DSP" ? 'selected' : '' }} value="SSP/DSP">SSP/DSP</option>
    <option {{ old('input_name') == "SSP" ? 'selected' : '' }} value="SSP">SSP</option>
    <option {{ old('input_name') == "DSP" ? 'selected' : '' }} value="DSP">DSP</option>
</select>
```

Your code becomes:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{route('dsp.report')}}">
    @csrf <!-- {{ csrf_field() }} -->
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label>Range one: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_from" name="date_from" value="{{ old('date_from') }}" placeholder="Date from range">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label>Range two: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_to" name="date_to" value="{{ old('date_to') }}" placeholder="Date to range">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label>Filter by SSP: </label>
        <select name="ssp_id[]" id="ssp" class="form-control-lg select2" multiple="multiple"><option></option></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label>Filter by DSP: </label>
        <select name="dsp_id[]" id="dsp" class="form-control-lg select2" multiple="multiple"><option></option></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label>Group by: </label>
        <select class="form-control" name="groupby">
            <option {{ old('groupby') == "SSP/DSP" ? 'selected' : '' }} value="SSP/DSP">SSP/DSP</option>
            <option {{ old('groupby') == "SSP" ? 'selected' : '' }} value="SSP">SSP</option>
            <option {{ old('groupby') == "DSP" ? 'selected' : '' }} value="DSP">DSP</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can add your select2 selected values this way:

```
let arrayOfSelectedValues = [] // You can keep your selected values here if you know them already

$('#ssp').select2({
    width: '200px',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: '{{ route("ssp") }}',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        quietMillis: 50,
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                term: term
            };
        },
    },
}).val(arrayOfSelectedValues).trigger("change"); // Then add the selected values to the select2() initialisation
```

Comment: What about select2 selects? It's the same usage of flash()/old() pair or different?

Comment: Yes, the <option value="some-value" {{ old('input_name') == "some-value" ? 'selected' : '' }}></option> should work for Select2 selects also.

Comment: "value="some-value" - And if we download values remotely from local controller and don't know the exact one? And another problem - it's a multiple list we have to unpack somehow. Should we run foreach for this in the blade template?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand what you mean by "download values remotely from local controller".

Comment: I mean we get these id/text pairs for select2 via ajax from the local database via laravel controller triggering the model with like '%pattern%' sql request.

Comment: I wish i could see what the method in your controller looks like. Can you please edit your question to show your controller method?

Comment: Well, first of all, we trigger this controller when we're looking for the SSP term: http://paste.org.ru/?sejtao And then we process chosen ids in the controller after submitting. Select2 has been configured in this way: http://paste.org.ru/?e5mn78 - the problem is that select2 sends only ids, not items (key/value pairs), and it's not possible to recover them from old() function as item names before sending.

Comment: After form reload - it doesn't work for select2's. Via ajax - we only get the list of items for select2 to show. After that we make POST request with selected keys and then reload the page. We have to preserve values after the page has been reloaded.

Comment: ".val(arrayOfSelectedValues).trigger("change");" - it's not SPA. We have to transfer select2 values to the same form, but with table below.

Comment: I updated my question with my own solution for this, but it seems we need to add <option> values in a different manner for select2. It raises error second time.

Answer (score 0):

Add the property **value** to all inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
```

Check the docs for better understanding https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#old-input